# Return all entities from an Expression<Func<T, bool>> Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

As the title says I want to return all entities which matches an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` in EF Core. I've created the FirstOrDefaultAsync, but I cannot find any way to return all entities which matches the predicate.

```
public async Task<TEntity> ReadAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
}
```

I've seen examples where the `Where` method is used, but this is not listed as an alternative method. How can I return all entities which matches the predicate in EF Core?

Comment: `FirstOrDefaultAsync` will return either one or no entries. Is this the intended effect?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane Yes, but I also want a method which also returns an IEnumerable<TEntity> that matches the predicate

Comment: Have a look at this https://kudchikarsk.com/repository-pattern-csharp/ specifically the `Get` method in the generic repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Where`. You should be aware that there is no async version of `Where`, since execution is deferred (i.e. `Where` will not cause the query to be executed on the DB, so there is no operation that can run asynchronously). If you want to keep your method async, you have to await a `ToListAsync` operation:

```
public async Task<List<TEntity>> ReadAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
}
```

Note that in cases when you immediately return from the async operation, you don't need to await and can save yourself the overhead of an `async` method:

```
public Task<List<TEntity>> ReadAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought the Where was a part of the EntityFramework.Core package. But of course its in System.Linq. I'll accept this answer as soon as I'm allowed to!

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is you do not find the Where(predicate) extension method, please verify that if you're referencing System.Linq.Queryable